# Laravel 9: replace interface implementation in tests?

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-9

Here is an example of how I declared my configuration for `MyService`

```
public function register(): void
{
    $this->app->when(MyService::class)
        ->needs(IUser::class)
        ->give(fn (Application $app) => $app->make(ICompanyUserProvider::class)->getCompanyUser());
}
```

So I want to replace `ICompanyUserProvider` implementation for testing purposes.

I have already seen a solution like this

```
$this->app->bind(
    ICompanyUserProvider::class, 
    $this->app->runningUnitTests() ? ProviderStub::class : Provider::class
);
```

it works, but I find it inappropriate, I don't think it's a good practice to mix enviorenments in a single configuration.

Here is what else I tried so far:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase as BaseTestCase;

abstract class TestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
     
        $this->app->bind(ICompanyUserProvider::class, ProviderStub::class);
    }
}
```

but it does not work (provider not being replaced with a stub one).

Any ideas, please?

Comment: You no need contextual binding. Just bind interface to implementation in provider, without using when/give - and all will works fine.

Comment: @Maksim I want to provide a concrete IUser instance, instead of passing the whole service

Comment: ok, try to `$this->app->instance(ICompanyUserProvider::class, ProviderStub::class);` in setUp()

Comment: @Maksim tried, does not work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use app->instance to replace an instance in applicationContainer, here is an example:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase as BaseTestCase;

abstract class TestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->app->instance(ICompanyUserProvider::class, new ProviderStub());
    }
}
```

If you look at the swap method from Facade class
`\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::swap` in line 182, they used the same method for replacing facade accessor with a fake instance.

Answer (score 0):

Your above code should be working.

```php
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase as BaseTestCase;

// add use from your ProviderStub class.

abstract class TestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
     
        $this->app->bind(ICompanyUserProvider::class, ProviderStub::class);
    }
}
```

#### Important

Confirm your test case extends `TestCase` from `use Tests\TestCase;` instead of `use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;`.

Feature tests will extends from `Tests\TestCase;` but unit tests is not.